# How to use hyperlink in sql server to display a pdf file?

Tags: sql, pdf, asp-classic, hyperlink, web

The title might be a little misleading but I'll explain what I need.

There is a page on my website which will show you a grid view. And this grid view will show you teachers data and one column will show the teacher's schedule as a link. Clicking the link will open a popup that will show a pdf file that is stored on the website folder.

I'm quite a beginner at using databases so I don't know what are the limitations.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 with SQL Management Studio 2012.

Comment: Where are the PDFs stored?

Answer (score 0):

Wht you need is to query your database with something like that :

```
SELECT teaches_schedules.pdf_link AS pdfLink
FROM teachers t
LEFT JOIN teaches_schedules ts ON ts.teacher_id = t.id
WHERE t.id = 1xx
```

Perhaps with a little example of your database structure we could help you.
This could be simpler or harder, depending on how your database is organized.